# Importing User Events in Google Cloud's Recommendation AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, recommendation-engine

I'm working on Google Cloud's Recommendation AI. For importing User Events, it supports BigQuery but can't find the Table Schema required. As it's in Beta, the community support and Documentation is limited. Can anyone please guide me in creating Table Schema for importing user events from BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/upload-catalog#bq), to import data from `BigQuery` you should use the [Recommendations AI Schema](https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/catalog#schema). The schema is a JSON schema like below:

```
[
    {
        "name": "product_metadata",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "images",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "uri",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "REQUIRED"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "height",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "width",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "exact_price",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REQUIRED",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "original_price",
                        "type": "FLOAT",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "display_price",
                        "type": "FLOAT",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "canonical_product_uri",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            },
            {
                "name": "currency_code",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "language_code",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "description",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "title",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    },
    {
        "name": "tags",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REPEATED"
    },
    {
        "name": "category_hierarchies",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "mode": "REPEATED",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "categories",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "REPEATED"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    }
]
```

Its also important to mention that you can also import data from Google Analytics. The reference for the Google Analytics schema can be found [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846?hl=en).

Comment: This is the schema for Product Catalog Table but I need help with User Events Table Schema. And my original data source is not Google Analytics so I want to modify the data to fit the BQ schema.

Comment: @DarshanMajithiya in this case if you need a unified schema you should use the Google Analytics schema